# pre-processing script to switch product codes

Tags: xslt

I have a snippet of code I've inherited and I'm trying to get it to work on multiples of the match pattern and set a tag from looking up a value from a table using another tag. What happens is that, for every item, the same lookup is performed and not the relative one for the node. I can't work out the syntax to work thru all entries and substitute the correct one. It's got to be simple it's just that I am simpler :)

My source xml contains this (within an outer /oomsdoc document node not shown):

```
<item>
<lineqty>     1</lineqty>
<linesku>BNLP5008       </linesku>
<linecustprod>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</linecustprod>
<linedesc>London Pride (Bot500mlx8)               </linedesc>
</item>

<item>
<lineqty>     1</lineqty>
<linesku>BNBL5008       </linesku>
<linecustprod>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</linecustprod>
<linedesc>Bengal Lancer (Bot500mlx8)              </linedesc>
</item>
```

I want to substitute the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx in each linecustprod tag with the material from the lookup table using the value of the linesku tag.

This is my lookup table:

```
<Materials>
    <product sku='BNLP5008       ' material='LONDON PRIDE'/>
    <product sku='BNBL5008       ' material='BENGAL LANCER'/>
</Materials>
```

and this is my xslt code.

```
    <xsl:variable name="SkuList" select="document('d:\test\transforms\catalogue.xml')/Materials"/>

<xsl:template match="/oomsdoc/item/linecustprod">
    <xsl:variable name="MySku" select="/oomsdoc/item/linesku"/>
    <linecustprod>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SkuList/product[@sku=$MySku]/@material"/>
    </linecustprod>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm guessing some kind of xsl foreach would work but just can't find a usable example to crib :)

Your guidance again would be appreciated at this point in my frustration :)

Thanks,

Brian.

Comment: Is your "lookup" table part of the same XML document, or a separate document? It would probably help if you showed how the **$SkuList** was defined in your XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC it was there, just hidden by a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the variable definition to

```
<xsl:variable name="MySku" select="../linesku"/>
```

should be sufficient, this will pull out the `linesku` that is a sibling to the `linecustprod` you're currently looking at. As currently defined the variable will contain a node set of *all* the `linesku` elements in the document, so the `value-of` will give you the first entry from `$SkuList` that matches *any* entry in the main input file.

Comment: Well that sorted it - thanks very much. I've used dot and dot-dot for years in the shells but haven't realised that it's as important in xslt until this came up :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ian Roberts' answer, please change

```
<xsl:variable name="SkuList" select="document('d:\test\transforms\catalogue.xml')/Materials"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="SkuList" select="document('/d:\test\transforms\catalogue.xml')/Materials"/>
```

for some reason, the first throws an error (malformed URL).

Comment: Thanks for this advice but for some reason with the custom processor this is used by, the current syntax works and when I "fix" it it fails. Weird, eh?